# Create generic shortcuts in Windows 10 using extended shell path

Tags: windows, shell, windows-10, shortcut-file

I want to create generic shortcuts in Windows 10 using a target path 
extension of the shell path, something like

```
%windir%\explorer.exe shell:AppData ..\Local\Temp
```

`%windir%\explorer.exe shell:AppData` works by itself, takes me to roaming userfiles.

I could use

```
%windir%\explorer.exe shell:UsersFilesFolder
```

which would take me to  `%UserProfile%` and append from there (if I could find out how) only it would be handy to be able to go up a level if possible as well.

I can't work out

- How to append a further couple directories into the shortcut target path
- How to go up one directory first (`..`?)

What is the syntax to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `%Temp%` might not be the same as `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp`!

The way to create a perfect shortcut to `%Temp%` is not that easy, ideally the .lnk should only contain a [EXP_SZ_LINK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773282(v=vs.85).aspx):EXP_SZ_LINK_SIG block with the `%Temp%` string. You have to manually delete the ItemIdList block to get a .lnk file like that. `%Temp%` is extra complicated because it does not have a special folder canonical name you can use with the shell: protocol.

I don't believe the shell: protocol supports `..` nor `.` path components.

`shell:AppData ..\Local` is also wrong because the local appdata folder might be somewhere else (< Windows Vista used different names) and a better command would be `%windir%\explorer.exe "shell:LocalAppData"` (and in turn `%windir%\explorer.exe "shell:Local AppData\Temp"`) but all of those commands have other issues.

First of all, Explorer might not be the users shell and you risk not obeying the users preferences.

Another problem is that a .lnk file contains the attributes of its target and because the link actually points to a .exe file your .lnk file will not have the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` bit set for its target attribute and the shell will not understand that it points to a folder. A .lnk that points to a folder will sometimes open in the same window when navigating the shell instead of opening a new file browser window.

The .lnk binary format is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx) and by breaking the rules a little bit I have been able to create a link that points to a file/folder inside a special shell folder by combining a [`EXP_SPECIAL_FOLDER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773279(v=vs.85).aspx) block with a manipulated ItemIdList but for whatever reason this trick does not work for deeper paths.

A `EXP_SPECIAL_FOLDER` block and a empty ItemIdList is the only way to create shortcuts to special folders that is guaranteed to work on all systems but you have to create it manually, the `IShellLink` implementation adds system specific blocks that might break things if you try to use the link on another system.

The .lnk format has not changed much since Windows 95 and there is simply no easy way to create shortcuts relative to special folders that also work when they are copied to other systems. The relative path string in a .lnk is relative to the .lnk file itself and is not helpful in this case.

I would recommend that you simply create the .lnk on the target system in your installer/application and let `IShellLink` fill in as much information as possible behind your back.